# Start back an activity that's been killed with finish() function?

Tags: android

After user logs in and goes to second screen(activity), I killed the Login screen activity using finish(). Now that I'am on second screen and I have Logout button there in the action bar, is there a way that login screen which has been killed can be brought back on log out button press ??

Comment: Just start a new LoginActivity?

Comment: You can always start the activity using Intent..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start it again.

```
startActivity(new Intent(CONTEXT, LoginActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

use this some line when you logout from second activity..